# How to get ListViewItem in ItemActivate event

Tags: c#, winforms, events, listview, listviewitem

I have a `ListView` with `ItemActivate` attached to it. Normally I would just use `listview.SelectedItems[0]` to get the `ListViewItem` that triggred the event.

Now I want to subscribe to `SelectedIndexChanged` as well so the items can get activated as soon as they are being selected.

Unfortunately the `sender` and `e` of both these events doesn't return the item which triggred the event (as far as I know!).

A workaround would be to have a field like `lvSelectedItem` and store the active item in it...but how can I do this a better way? Somehow that I can get the selected item directly from sender or eventargs ?

Here is my code:

```
    private void lvPins_ItemActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var item = lvPins.SelectedItems[0];
        var pin = item.Tag as Pin;
        OnPinActivated(pin);
    }

    private void lvPins_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var item = lvPins.SelectedItems[0]; //this always cause argumentoutofrange exceotion
        var pin = item.Tag as Pin;
        OnPinActivated(pin);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedindexchanged.aspx) of `SelectedIndexChanged`:

> To determine which items are selected in the ListView control, use the SelectedItems property to access the ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection

You can't access the new selected item / items from the event arguments.

If you don't want to keep a reference to the `ListView` you can use the `sender` for accessing it:

```
 ((ListView)sender).SelectedItems
```

**UPDATE ACCORDING TO THE POSTED CODE:**

I think that the `SelectedIndexChanged` is fired twice:

- When removing the old selected items to `SelectedItems` list (and then you get an empty list)
- When adding the new selected items to `Selecteditems` list (the second time you will get the the selected item then)

try changing your code to that:

```
if (lvPins.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
{
    var item = lvPins.SelectedItems[0]; //the second time you will get the selected item here
    var pin = item.Tag as Pin;
    OnPinActivated(pin);
}
```